# testing a function within a component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jestjs

Trying to use jest to write a unit test for the following function, up untill now i have been exporting functions outside of the class to test, my problem now is a function is within a class and i dont know how to properly test it. 
The below handleRequest is within a class

```
 handleRequestSort(event, property) {
    const orderBy = property;
    let order = 'desc';

    if (this.state.orderBy === property && this.state.order === 'desc') {
        order = 'asc';
    }

    this.setState({ order, orderBy });
}

   describe('Test for handleRequestSort', () => {
    it('should handle the sorting of a request', () => {
     const ordering = Contract.handleRequestSort(null, 'name');
     expect(ordering).toEqual('name');
    });
    });
```

Comment: `describe('Test for handleRequestSort', () => {
    it('should handle the sorting of a request', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<ContractTable />); wrapper.instance().handleRequestSort(null, 'name');
        expect(wrapper).toEqual('name');
    });
});`  tried something like this but to no avail

Comment: How exactly is `handleRequestSort()` executed by a component instance? The point would be to trigger that method indirectly via the event that internally calls the `handleRequestSort()` method for that component instance then check the results after it has executed. For example, if it triggers because of a click event on some button on that component, to trigger/simulate a click then validate `order`, `orderBy` state values have updated as you expect.

Comment: it is passed into another component onRequestSort={this.handleRequestSort}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invoke a function with enzyme when function is passed down as prop - React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064334/invoke-a-function-with-enzyme-when-function-is-passed-down-as-prop-react)

Comment: Check out the answer. You can effectively find the child component, execute the respective prop function bound to that child component, then validate results (state changed as you expect).

Answer (score 0):

You're close.

Here is a working example based on the code you provided:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

class ContractTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = { };
  }
  handleRequestSort(event, property) {
    const orderBy = property;
    let order = 'desc';

    if (this.state.orderBy === property && this.state.order === 'desc') {
      order = 'asc';
    }

    this.setState({ order, orderBy });
  }
  render() { return null; }
}

describe('Test for handleRequestSort', () => {
  it('should handle the sorting of a request', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<ContractTable />);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();
    instance.handleRequestSort(null, 'name');
    expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual({ order: 'desc', orderBy: 'name' });  // SUCCESS
    instance.handleRequestSort(null, 'name');
    expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual({ order: 'asc', orderBy: 'name' });  // SUCCESS
    instance.handleRequestSort(null, 'address');
    expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual({ order: 'desc', orderBy: 'address' });  // SUCCESS
  });
});
```

Comment: For those who have searched for this answer and are trying to test a stateless component, be aware that in React 16 and above, instance() returns null for stateless functional components. [link](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/instance.html).